# @Autowired(required = false) fails after removing bean

Tags: java, spring

Steps to reproduce on https://github.com/nowszy94/Autowired-null

After removing bean from Spring context with `BeanDefinitionRegistry:removeBeanDefinition` method, `@Autowired(required = false)` spring throws error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'helloService' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolvedCachedArgument(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$200(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:538) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Where have you defined the `helloService` bean?

Comment: @CKing https://github.com/nowszy94/Autowired-null/blob/master/src/main/java/com/szymon/Application.java

Comment: It's better to add the code directly to the question, that way if/when the link breaks, the question will still have context/value.

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring occurs at bean creation. If you did not have a helloService bean defined, then your spring application would not throw an exception when attempting to satisfy that dependency during bean creation. In your example you are removing the helloService bean from the application context after it has already been wired into your HelloController bean.

Comment: But it's still setup to `required=false`, so it should give null, instead of exception.

Comment: Like I said, autowiring is a startup process. That "required" is only saying to spring "hey if you can't satisfy this dependency when initializing this bean don't fail". Once Spring has started up @Autowire is no longer relevant.

Comment: I tried to debug this, and I've seen that controller bean is created for each request. So autowired works while bean creation. Removing bean from context gives situation, when next beans should have null in that field, and exception shouldn't be thrown.

Comment: Are you sure you are interpreting your debugger correctly? A Controller is a singleton, a new instance of the bean shouldn't be created with each request. Also as a clarification for others, Autowire applies at the creation of a bean, not just startup of an application as I have previously said.

Comment: I've setup breakpoint on my constructor, and it was caught in second request (after `helloService` bean was removed). After commented bean removing line i can see it's really a singleton(constructor breakpoint is not caught).

Comment: Possibly my controller bean was removed after removing `helloService`. It looks that next creations avoiding `required=false`